# Calling Bing or IBM text-to-speech API in Python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Is there a way to call the Bing Text To Speech API or the IBM Text To Speech API through Python?

Maybe in the fashion that Python's [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) library works?

Answer (score 3):

For Bing translation, set `BING_KEY=**your key**`.

You could then do translation as `bing_en_US=recognizer.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY, language="en-US")`.

Ref: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Get your key here:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=speech-api

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can add:

```
return recognizer.recognize_ibm(audio)
```

in the code after downloading everything you need including the IBM zip file here:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-websockets-python

heres the entire code:

```
import speech_recognition


while 1:
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

    def listen():

            with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
                    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                    audio = recognizer.listen(source)

            try:
                    # return recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio) 
                    #return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                    return recognizer.recognize_ibm(audio)
            except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
                    print("Could not understand audio")
            except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
                    print("Recog Error; {0}".format(e))

            return ""


    listen()

    print (listen())
```